# Android Material Design on KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, material-design

I am starting to learn Android development. I read on the Google dev site that Material Design is only available on Android 5.0. I wonder why some applications on Android 4.4 have material design. I am using Android 4.4. Any guides or tips give me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a design backward compatibility library that bring important material design components to Android 2.1 and above.

See : 
http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Generally speaking, Android always provides some support libraries to provide backward compatibility to previous version on Android.

You will find all you need here :
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 2):

First I should remember Material Design isn't only some code or component else ,It's totally a concept about how design your app to get best UI/UX.

And yes ,android 5 and above ,have some pretty and new features and components ,that you can use some of them in android <5 by some support library that Google or someone else provide them ,
for example look at these two lib:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7
com.android.support:design
```

these are most useful libs by Google to have material components in android <5 development.